# Loading a new grammar in Microsoft.Speech.Recognition

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, asynchronous, speech-recognition

I am building a program that uses the new microsoft.speech API. When I first start the program I load my SpeechRecognizer with a grammar and everything is fine. However, I also am using the Microsoft Async CTP to do some work to retrieve a word to be added to the grammar and when it returns I want to load a new grammar. Bellow is the Async CTP portion...

```
class UR
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancelationToken;

    public UR()
    {
        _cancelationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    public async void StartRecognition()
    {
        String someword = await Recognize(_cancelationToken.Token);
        //Load the new grammar
        SpeechRecognizer sr = SpeechRecognizer.Instance;
        sr.LoadNewGrammar(someword);
    }
}
```

Here is the LoadNewGrammar method, in order to load the new grammar you will see that I am trying to use "RecognizeAsyncCancel" to stop the recognizer, then load the grammar and user "RecognizeAsync" to restart the recognizer.

```
    public void LoadNewGrammar(String someword)
    {
        Commands = new Dictionary<string, WhatSaid>()
        {
            {"DoThis",         new WhatSaid()      {verb=Verbs.DoThis}},
            {"DoThat",         new WhatSaid()      {verb=Verbs.DoThat}},
            {someword,         new WhatSaid()      {verb=Verbs.Someword}}
        };

        if (sre == null)
        {
            RecognizerInfo ri = GetKinectRecognizer();
            sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ri);
        }
        //Stop the speech recognizer temporarily in order to load the new grammar
        sre.RecognizeAsyncCancel();

        // Build a grammar of commands
        var basicCmds = new Choices();
        foreach (var phrase in Commands)
        {
            basicCmds.Add(phrase.Key);
        }

        // Combine all choices 
        var allChoices = new Choices();
        allChoices.Add(basicCmds);

        //Create a grammar builder to be used in the grammar object
        var gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Culture = sre.RecognizerInfo.Culture; 
        gb.Append(allChoices);

        var g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);
        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
```

The problem seems to be that when I call sre.RecognizeAsyncCancel my program completely freezes up. I have also tried RecognizeAsyncStop with the same result. I have a feeling that because I am having a threading issue here but have no idea where to begin to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this :

http://blogs.interknowlogy.com/2011/11/23/speechrecognitionengine-grammar-choices-and-updating-them-dynamically/

Regards